# Export a TypeScript class more than once

Tags: typescript

Is there any way to export a class more than once in TypeScript?

The following works but the second export isn't treated as a class:

```
export module foo {
   export class bar {
   }
}

export var bar = foo.bar;
```

Is there a way to make both work:

```
import "foo"

class baz extends foo.bar {
}
```

and

```
import {bar} from "foo"

class baz extends bar {
}
```

Comment: This feels like a bug to me. `bar` has the `typeof foo.bar` type but not extendable...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is essentially the same as this:

```
class foo {
}

var bar = foo;

class baz extends bar { // error: cannot find name 'bar'
}
```

...which isn't supported by the language. Using a type alias won't work either.

The only workaround I can think of is to do this:

```
export module foo {
   export class bar {
   }
}

export class bar extends foo.bar {}
```